# My Gnome session on Centos 7.0 crashes and sends me back to the login screen

Tags: linux, gnome, centos-7

This happens 5 or six times a day.   I don't know where to start.  This is from /var/log/messages:

```
org.gnome.Shell.desktop: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
org.gnome.Shell.desktop: after 3575 requests (3575 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
journal: gsd-xsettings: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
org.a11y.atspi.Registry: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
org.a11y.atspi.Registry: after 48317 requests (48317 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
journal: gsd-wacom: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
journal: gsd-clipboard: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
journal: gnome-shell: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
journal: gsd-power: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
journal: gsd-color: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
journal: gsd-keyboard: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
journal: gsd-locate-pointer: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
journal: gsd-media-keys: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
journal: abrt: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
gnome-session-binary[16856]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop' exited with code 1
journal: gnome-terminal-server: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
org.gtk.vfs.Daemon: A connection to the bus can't be made
com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1547641910.885832]: IMSettings-Daemon[16935]: INFO: Release the ownership of com.redhat.imsettings
com.redhat.imsettings: Exiting...
com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1547641910.886263]: GLib-GIO[16935]: CRITICAL **: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed
com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1547641910.886360]: GLib-GIO[16935]: CRITICAL **: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed
com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1547641910.886509]: IMSettings-Daemon[16935]: INFO: Unloading imesttings module: gsettings
com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1547641910.886648]: IMSettings-Daemon[16935]: INFO: imsettings-daemon is shut down.
gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[16856]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop' exited with code 1
gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[16856]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Clipboard.desktop' exited with code 1
gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[16856]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[16856]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop' exited with code 1
```